# Network Latency Simulation

Tags: networking, windows-7

Does anyone know of any tool that we could install on a Windows 7 workstation that will simulate Latency? I know you can get software that will throtle the connection but that is not what I am looking for.

What I am after is a simulation of an application having responses from a server come back slowly causing the UI to freeze (which I believe is due to the vendor making network calls on the GUI thread).

Comment: https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like MS has a tool that does exactly what I am after but don't officially support it.

Tool is called Network Emulation Windows Toolkit. And someone has uploaded it here: :)

http://blog.mrpol.nl/2010/01/14/network-emulator-toolkit/

Answer (score 1):

There's always [Nistnet](http://www-x.antd.nist.gov/nistnet/).  Developed by the US government.  Works on linux.  Quite old, but tried and tested, so they say.

Might work under cygwin on Windows 7.  Dunno.

A quick google for Network latency simulator brings up this as a possible option.  I bet it's not cheap tho: http://packetstorm.com/psc/psc.nsf/site/tornado-software

Answer (score 1):

Little late in the game here, but you should check out some purpose-built network emulation hardware if you're trying to validate application performance in a lab.

I used the Linktropy by Apposite Tech at my last job.

http://www.apposite-tech.com

There's some freeware out there, but it's a real pain in the butt.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this site has private messaging, but I have a network bandwidth simulator you drop on two machines. You could basically use the tool and perhaps cutting the network card to 10mbps half duplex to effectively neuter the connection, latency will be pretty awful.

Comment: Tom, there is no private messaging. But if you give us the name of the simulator that would be great - and help the greater good(tm).